# How to use zmq inside a function (in a non-blocking manner) to obtain the function's state when requested by a client?

Tags: python, c++, zeromq, pyzmq

How to use ZMQ in a non-blocking manner to "serve" the status of a long running job when the status is requested by a client?

The below code illustrates how the long running task could be temporarily "interrupted" to send the current status.

The task is long running because there are many `urls` to process, and not because each url takes a long time to process. This would mean that the server could respond to the client with the current status almost instantly.

I have been unable to implement this logic in a non-blocking manner as using the flag `zmq.NOBLOCK` results in `Again: Resource temporarily unavailable`, and not using the flag means that the server blocks and waits to receive a message.

How to achieve such logic/behaviour? I am open to using either a C++ or Python.

**Server code:**

```
import zmq

# Socket details
port = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)

# List of many urls
urls = ['http://google.com','http://yahoo.com']

def process(url):
    """Sample function"""
    pass

processed_urls = []
for url in urls:

    # If a message has been received by a client respond to the message
    # The response should be the current status.
    if socket.recv(zmq.NOBLOCK):
        msg = b"Processed the following urls %s" % str(processed_urls).encode()
        socket.send(msg, zmq.NOBLOCK)

    # Continue processing the urls
    process(url)
    processed_urls.append(url)
```

Comment: Ok, the first problem is that you're using a PAIR socket over TCP. That's not supported according to http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket. That might have quite a lot to do with it. Older versions documented PAIRs as "experimental".

Comment: Oh, and `Again:...` is the proper response by `recv` when used non-blocking when there is no message to receive. The 'again' means that you're going to have to call it again if you actually want to receive a message, because there wasn't one ready at the time; the client hasn't sent one yet. So for your application, simply catch the `Again:...` and carry on processing URLs; it just means that the client hasn't asked for status information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - NON-BLOCKING is a dual-side sword. There are two worlds, each of which CAN and sometimes DOES block.

1. The **GIL**-side and/or **process**-side **"blocking"** can appear ( **`numpy`** example below, but valid for any sync-blocking calls that cannot have any easily achievable non-blocking workaround ) while some external process or a global application architecture may still need to have ( at least ) some responding & hand-shaking behaviour from even such knowingly "blocked" Python code-areas.
2. The second world is **your ZeroMQ** (potentially)-blocking **call**. Seting a `zmq.CONFLATE` may additionally help you in PUSH-like URL-reporting from long-job running client to server. Set **`CONFLATE`** both on client and server side of the reporting socket.

In every place where I can I do advocate for strictly non-blocking designs. Even the school-book examples of ZeroMQ code ought be realistic and fair not to block. We live in the 3rd Millenium and a blocking code is a performance & resources-usage devastating state, principally outside of one's domain of control in professional grade distributed-systems' design.

---

### A principal scaffolding:

```
####################################################################
### NEED TO VIEW aHealthSTATUS FROM AN EXTERNAL_UNIVERSE:
### ( A LIGHTWEIGHT EXCULPATED MONITOR TO OBSERVE THE HEALTH OF THE EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT FROM OUTSIDE OF THE VM-JAIL, FROM AN OUTER HYPERVISOR SPACE )
### ( + using signal.signal() )

import signal, os
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# .SET  ZeroMQ INFRASTRUCTURE:

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# .DEF  SIG_handler(s)

def SIG_handler_based_HealthREPORTER( SIGnum, aFrame ):
    print( 'SIG_handler called to report state with signal', SIGnum )
    #---------------------------------------------------------------
    # ZeroMQ .send( .SIG/.MSG )
    
    pass;   # yes, all the needed magic comes right here
    
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------
    # FINALLY:
    
    raise OSError( "Had to send a HealthREPORT" )                   # ??? do we indeed need this circus to be always played around, except in a DEMO-mode?

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# .ASSOC SIG_handler:

signal.signal( signal.SIGALRM, SIG_handler_based_HealthREPORTER )   # .SET { SIGALRM: <aHandler> }-assoc

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# .SET 1[sec]-delay + 1[sec]-interval

signal.setitimer( signal.ITIMER_REAL, 1, 1 )                        # .SET REAL-TIME Interval-based WatchDog -- Decrements interval timer in real time, and delivers SIGALRM upon expiration.


# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# FINALLY:


#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# .SET / .DEACTIVATE 
signal.setitimer( signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0 )                           # .SET / DEACTIVATE

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# .TERM GRACEFULLY ZeroMQ INFRASTRUCTURE


#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLEAN EXIT(0)
_exit(0)
```

---

Let me share an approach used for a sort of `aHealthMONITOR` on an indeed a long principally-BLOCKING computation cases.

Let's take one example of a GIL-"blocking" type of computations:

```
#######
# SETUP
signal.signal(    signal.SIGALRM, SIG_ALRM_handler_A )          # .ASSOC { SIGALRM: thisHandler }
signal.setitimer( signal.ITIMER_REAL, 10, 5 )                   # .SET   @5 [sec] interval, after first run, starting after 10[sec] initial-delay
SIG_ALRM_last_ctx_switch_VOLUNTARY = -1                         # .RESET .INIT()
```

Mechanics of **`SIGALRM`** + **`ITIMER_REAL`** deliver a lovely automation to keep external worlds happy with at least some responsiveness ( as frequent as ~ 0.2 [Hz] in this example, but principally {up-|down-}-scalable to any reasonable & yet system-wide stable amount of time **--** testing a 0.5 [GHz] handler on a 1.0 [GHz] VM-system is left for a kind ultimate hacker's consideration **--** otherwise a common sense for reasonable factors of scale and non-blocking/low-latency designs apply )

DEMO readouts show, how **`involuntary=`** context switches demonstrate the blocking-indifferent mechanics ( read the numbers, as they grow, while voluntary remain the same throughout the whole GIL-blocking part of the process ), so a similarly **`def`**-ed **`SIG_ALRM_handler_XYZ()`** **can provide a solution to your process-state independent on-demand reporter.**

```
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): activated             Wed Oct 19 14:13:14 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53151, involuntary=1169)

>>> SIG_ALRM_last_ctx_switch_VOLUNTARY                              53243
>>> SIG_ALRM_last_ctx_switch_FORCED                                  1169

>>> [ np.math.factorial( 2**f ) for f in range(20) ][:5]            # too fast to notice @5[sec]
[1, 2, 24, 40320, 20922789888000]

#########
# COMPUTE
# len(str([np.math.factorial(2**f) for f in range(20)][-1]))    # .RUN   A "FAT"-BLOCKING CHUNK OF A regex/numpy/C/FORTRAN-calculus

>>> len( str( [ np.math.factorial( 2**f ) for f in range(20) ][-1] ) )
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:15:39 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1234)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a Stateful-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:15:44 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1257)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a Stateful-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:15:49 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1282)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:15:54 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1305)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:15:59 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1330)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:04 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1352)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:09 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1377)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:14 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1400)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:19 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1425)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:24 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1448)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:29 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1473)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:34 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1496)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:39 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1521)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:44 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1543)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:49 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1568)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:54 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1591)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:16:59 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1616)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:17:04 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1639)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:17:09 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1664)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:17:14 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1687)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:17:19 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1713)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:17:24 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1740)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:17:29 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1767)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:17:34 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1790)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD::  Wed Oct 19 14:17:39 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=53366, involuntary=1812)  INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection
2771010
```

In this process-context, there was used this handler:

```
########################################################################
### SIGALRM_handler_          
###

import psutil, resource, os, time
        
SIG_ALRM_last_ctx_switch_VOLUNTARY = -1
SIG_ALRM_last_ctx_switch_FORCED    = -1

def SIG_ALRM_handler_A( aSigNUM, aFrame ):                              # SIG_ALRM fired evenly even during [ np.math.factorial( 2**f ) for f in range( 20 ) ] C-based processing =======================================
    #
    # onEntry_ROTATE_SigHandlers() -- MAY set another sub-sampled SIG_ALRM_handler_B() ... { last: 0, 0: handler_A, 1: handler_B, 2: handler_C }
    #
    # onEntry_SEQ of calls of regular, hierarchically timed MONITORS ( just the SNAPSHOT-DATA ACQUISITION Code-SPRINTs, handle later due to possible TimeDOMAIN overlaps )
    # 
    aProcess         =   psutil.Process( os.getpid() )
    aProcessCpuPCT   =         aProcess.cpu_percent( interval = 0 )     # EVENLY-TIME-STEPPED
    aCtxSwitchNUMs   =         aProcess.num_ctx_switches()              # THIS PROCESS ( may inspect other per-incident later ... on anomaly )
    
    aVolCtxSwitchCNT = aCtxSwitchNUMs.voluntary
    aForcedSwitchCNT = aCtxSwitchNUMs.involuntary
    
    global SIG_ALRM_last_ctx_switch_VOLUNTARY
    global SIG_ALRM_last_ctx_switch_FORCED
    
    if (     SIG_ALRM_last_ctx_switch_VOLUNTARY != -1 ):                # .INIT VALUE STILL UNCHANGED
        #----------
        # .ON_TICK: must process delta(s)
        if ( SIG_ALRM_last_ctx_switch_VOLUNTARY == aVolCtxSwitchCNT ):
            #
            # AN INDIRECT INDICATION OF A LONG-RUNNING WORKLOAD OUTSIDE GIL-STEPPING ( regex / C-lib / FORTRAN / numpy-block et al )
            #                                                                                 |||||              vvv
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:24:32 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=48714, involuntary=315)  ~~~  0.0
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:24:37 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=48714, involuntary=323)  ~~~  0.0
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:24:42 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=48714, involuntary=331)  ~~~  0.0
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:24:47 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=48714, involuntary=338)  ~~~  0.0
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:24:52 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=48714, involuntary=346)  ~~~  0.0
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:24:57 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=48714, involuntary=353)  ~~~  0.0
            # ...                                                                             |||||              ^^^
            # 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
            # >>>                                                                             |||||              |||
            #                                                                                 vvvvv              |||
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:26:17 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=49983, involuntary=502)  ~~~  0.0
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:26:22 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=49984, involuntary=502)  ~~~  0.0
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:26:27 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=49985, involuntary=502)  ~~~  0.0
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:26:32 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=49986, involuntary=502)  ~~~  0.0
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:26:37 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=49987, involuntary=502)  ~~~  0.0
            # SIG_:  Wed Oct 19 12:26:42 2016 ------------------------------ pctxsw(voluntary=49988, involuntary=502)  ~~~  0.0                
            print(   "SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): A SUSPECT CPU-LOAD:: ", time.ctime(), 10 * "-",  aProcess.num_ctx_switches(), "{0:_>60s}".format( str( aProcess.threads() ) ),          " INSPECT processes ... ev. add a StateFul-self-Introspection" )
    else:
        #----------
        # .ON_INIT: may report .INIT()
        print(   "SIG_ALRM_handler_A(): activated            ", time.ctime(), 30 * "-",  aProcess.num_ctx_switches() )
    
    ##########
    # FINALLY:
    
    SIG_ALRM_last_ctx_switch_VOLUNTARY = aVolCtxSwitchCNT               # .STO ACTUALs
    SIG_ALRM_last_ctx_switch_FORCED    = aForcedSwitchCNT               # .STO ACTUALs
```

Comment: I find your code Really Hard to read. Can you PEP-8 it?